# How to use WHERE statement on JSON stored in Presto SQL column to filter?

Tags: sql, json, filter, presto

In Presto, I have data for a column in a table is as follows:

| header | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| {Data: [{'item1': 'stuff1', 'item2': 'stuff2', 'item3': 'stuff3'}, {...}]} | cell 2 |
| {Data: [{'item1': 'stuff11', 'item2': 'stuff21', 'item3': 'stuff31'}, {...}]} | cell 4 |

I was able to SELECT using JSON syntax using:

`SELECT header.Data[1].item1 FROM table`

and returns:

| header |
| --- |
| stuff1 |
| stuff11 |

However, if I want to filter the table using the WHERE statement:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE header.Data[1].item1 = 'stuff1'`

The above statement threw an error and didn't work.

I would like to return something like

| header | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| {Data: [{'item1': 'stuff1', 'item2': 'stuff2', 'item3': 'stuff3'}, {...}]} | cell 2 |

Any input would be helpful. Thanks

I've tried several other queries using SQL as well such as but all returned similar error:

`WHERE header.Data[1].item1 = 'stuff1'`

An example of the error:

Query:

```
`SELECT header.Data[1].item1 AS f FROM table WHERE f LIKE '%stuff%'
```

'''
An error occurred while calling o12.execute. : java.sql.SQLException: Query failed (#20220330_200148_01673_9bq5k): line 2:7: Column 'f' cannot be resolved at io.prestosql.jdbc.AbstractPrestoResultSet.resultsException(AbstractPrestoResultSet.java:1761) at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.getColumns(PrestoResultSet.java:252) at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.create(PrestoResultSet.java:54) at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:249) at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoStatement.execute(PrestoStatement.java:227) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: io.prestosql.spi.PrestoException: line 2:7: Column 'f' cannot be resolved at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.SemanticExceptions.semanticException(SemanticExceptions.java:48) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.SemanticExceptions.semanticException(SemanticExceptions.java:43) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.SemanticExceptions.missingAttributeException(SemanticExceptions.java:33) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.Scope.lambda$resolveField$7(Scope.java:228) at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.Scope.resolveField(Scope.java:228) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.visitIdentifier(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:438) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.visitIdentifier(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:342) at io.prestosql.sql.tree.Identifier.accept(Identifier.java:72) at io.prestosql.sql.tree.StackableAstVisitor.process(StackableAstVisitor.java:27) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.process(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:365) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.visitLikePredicate(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:702) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.visitLikePredicate(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:342) at io.prestosql.sql.tree.LikePredicate.accept(LikePredicate.java:76) at io.prestosql.sql.tree.StackableAstVisitor.process(StackableAstVisitor.java:27) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.process(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:365) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer.analyze(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:303) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer.analyzeExpression(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:1691) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.analyzeExpression(StatementAnalyzer.java:2606) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.analyzeWhere(StatementAnalyzer.java:2465) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.lambda$visitQuerySpecification$23(StatementAnalyzer.java:1528) at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuerySpecification(StatementAnalyzer.java:1528) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuerySpecification(StatementAnalyzer.java:322) at io.prestosql.sql.tree.QuerySpecification.accept(QuerySpecification.java:144) at io.prestosql.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:339) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:349) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuery(StatementAnalyzer.java:1039) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuery(StatementAnalyzer.java:322) at io.prestosql.sql.tree.Query.accept(Query.java:107) at io.prestosql.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:339) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer.analyze(StatementAnalyzer.java:308) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:83) at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:75) at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution.analyze(SqlQueryExecution.java:256) at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution.(SqlQueryExecution.java:182) at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution$SqlQueryExecutionFactory.createQueryExecution(SqlQueryExecution.java:757) at io.prestosql.dispatcher.LocalDispatchQueryFactory.lambda$createDispatchQuery$0(LocalDispatchQueryFactory.java:123) at io.prestosql.$gen.Presto_343____20220330_135137_2.call(Unknown Source) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
'''

Comment: use open json function ref:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=OPENJSON%20is%20a%20table%2Dvalued,used%20to%20populate%20the%20columns.

Comment: _"The above statement threw an error and didn't work."_ what error has it thrown?

Comment: What is the type of first column? You can use `select typeof(header)` to determine it.

Comment: @GuruStron, Error message added. Sorry the network went down and could not add it yesterday.

Comment: Can you please add the whole query?

Comment: Cause I don't see anything in provided ones that can lead to `Column 'f' cannot be resolved at`

Comment: @GuruStron whole query added. WIthout the WHERE statement, the query returns a whole column of "stuff". However, I am only interested in some of the "Stuff" not all the "stuff" so would like to Filter by that.

Answer (score 1):

Alias `f` introduced by `SELECT header.Data[1].item1 AS f` is not available in `WHERE` so you need to use the whole expression:

```sql
where header.Data[1].item1 LIKE '%stuff%'
```